# Power BI DAX counting rows based on a condition that gets a few rows from another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three columns in my table:
A - event values that user does on an app
B - success or error
C - unique ID - used for counting totals

I want to find out the count of events in A, when there is at least one [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixneW.png) in B.

I have a measure: c-events = countrows of C.
If i run this code: `Error Events = CALCULATE([C-events], FILTER(Query1, Query1[B]="error"))` Then I get 2 as the number, but I want to get 6 as the answer, since I want to get the total of all values in A that had at least 1 error in B. Any thoughts on how I could do it in Dax?

Answer (score 1):

So if I am understanding correctly based on the image you provided, you are essentially looking to sum the values in C where the value of B is error? If so, I think this should work:

```
Error Events = CALCULATE(SUM([C-events]), FILTER(Query1, Query1[B]="error"))
```

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks so much for looking into this, however, sum([C-events]) is erroring out, since C-events is a measure and not a column.

Comment: @nukalanagendra COUNTROWS looks at a whole table rather than a column, so the reason why you're getting a value of two using c-events is because there are two rows in the table that contain B value of error. If you were looking for the sum of values in C when B=Error, try this: 

Error Events = CALCULATE(SUM('Query1'[C]), FILTER('Query1', [B]="error"))